# How to text search / filter in web3?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nft, erc-721, opensea

I have created a list of ERC721 NFTs in different contracts using thirdwebsdk, I need a way to text search, for example, nfts with the name as "cat" and get the list of all nfts which has "cat" in its metadata.

I heard we can't query on the blockchain. So how can do the text search like opensea, is web3 or any other sdk support this?
Do we need to keep a copy of all the nfts I create into a database for querying.

Comment: What are you trying to "text search"? NFTs name metadata, ...

Comment: @Ismael, I am trying to do a search based on NFT name, NFT description, etc. But couldn't find any methods related to doing such a search?

Comment: Metadata is offchain so you'll need a thirdparty api like opensea, etherscan, thegraph, moralis, etc, or indexing it yourself.